# JQgrid - Get Row Number instead of ID

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, methods, rowid

I am creating a JQGrid from a database table that does not contain a single field primary key.
Therefore, the field i am supplying as id is not unique and the same one exists in several rows.

Because of this, when passing a reference to the data with ondblClickRow to a function external to the grid i need to use the rownumber and not the id.

To test, I'm using `ondblClickRow: function(id){alert($("#grid1").getInd('rowid'));},` , and i should be getting and alert with the row number, except that it isn't working.

I've been over the documentation and can't understand what i am doing wrong...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Mario.

Bellow is my full grid:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var mygrid = jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid({
    datatype: 'xmlstring',
    datastr : grid1RsXML,
    width: 1024,
    height: 500,
    colNames:['DEVICE_ID','JOB_SIZE_IN_BYTES', 'USER_NAME','HOST_NAME','DAY_OF_WEEK','JOB_ID'],
    colModel:[ 
                {name:'DEVICE_ID',index:'DEVICE_ID', width:55, sortable:true},
                {name:'JOB_SIZE_IN_BYTES',index:'JOB_SIZE_IN_BYTES', width:40, sortable:true},
                {name:'USER_NAME',index:'USER_NAME', width:60, sortable:true},
                {name:'HOST_NAME',index:'HOST_NAME', width:50,align:"right", sortable:true},
                {name:'DAY_OF_WEEK',index:'DAY_OF_WEEK', width:10, sortable:true},
                {name:'JOB_ID',index:'JOB_ID', width:30, sortable:true}

             ],
    rowNum:1000,
    autowidth: true, 
    //rowList:[10,20,30],
    rowList:[1],
    pager: '#grid1Pager',
    sortname: 'DEVICE_ID',
    viewrecords: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    sortable: true,
    gridview : true,
    xmlReader: { root : "recordset", row: "record", repeatitems: false, id: "DEVICE_ID" },
    caption:"All Jobs - Double Click for detailed history",
    ondblClickRow: function(id){alert($("#grid1").getInd('rowid'));}, 
    toolbar: [true,"top"],
    url: grid1RsXML
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you can use the getInd() method, like this:

```
var sel_id = $grid.getGridParam('selrow');
var index = $grid1.jqGrid('getInd',sel_id); // counting from 1
```

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is already passed to the event, you just need to include more of the available parameters in your function declaration:

```
ondblClickRow: function(id, iRow, iCol, e) {
    alert(iRow);
},
```

Comment: +1 - Just curious, this should not matter for this particular question, but what happens to iRow when the grid is sorted? Presumably it would change to match the new ordering of rows?

Comment: Yes, it would.  Rather than doing things based on row, I would send down the composite key into hidden columns so that they could be used for subsequent requests.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of your main question gives you great_llama, but it seams to me, that you a little misunderstand `id` as a XML input used by jqGrid. Default `xmlReader` has `id: "[id]"`. So you just remove `id: "DEVICE_ID"` from the definition of `xmlReader` and place `id` attribute in your data:

```
var grid1RsXML = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"+
  "<recordset>"+
      "<rows>"+
          "<record id='1'>"+
              "<DEVICE_ID>data1</DEVICE_ID>"+
              "<JOB_SIZE_IN_BYTES>data2</JOB_SIZE_IN_BYTES>"+
              "<USER_NAME>data3</USER_NAME>"+
              "<HOST_NAME>data4</HOST_NAME>"+
              "<DAY_OF_WEEK>data5</DAY_OF_WEEK>"+
              "<JOB_ID>data6</JOB_ID>"+
          "</record>"+
          "<record id='2'>"+
              "<DEVICE_ID>data1</DEVICE_ID>"+
              "<JOB_SIZE_IN_BYTES>data2</JOB_SIZE_IN_BYTES>"+
              "<USER_NAME>data3</USER_NAME>"+
              "<HOST_NAME>data4</HOST_NAME>"+
              "<DAY_OF_WEEK>data5</DAY_OF_WEEK>"+
              "<JOB_ID>data6</JOB_ID>"+
          "</record>"+
          "<record id='3'>"+
              "<DEVICE_ID>data1</DEVICE_ID>"+
              "<JOB_SIZE_IN_BYTES>data2</JOB_SIZE_IN_BYTES>"+
              "<USER_NAME>data3</USER_NAME>"+
              "<HOST_NAME>data4</HOST_NAME>"+
              "<DAY_OF_WEEK>data5</DAY_OF_WEEK>"+
              "<JOB_ID>data6</JOB_ID>"+
          "</record>"+
      "</rows>"+
  "</recordset>";
```

So your main data which send your server could have double rows, but if you just add `id` attribute which can be a row counter you can solve your problem. The value of `id` attribute must not be a number, you can use any string instead. If the nature of your data allow this, you can produce an unique `id` as a string composed from your other data.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had same requirement, i.e to access the row data by row number rather than the row id. I don't have any row id. Below code works for me. NOTE: The row count starts from 1.

`var rowNum=$("#grid1").getGridParam("selarrrow");
$("#grid1").getRowData(rowNum);`

Answer (score 0):

I make it like this:

```
ondblClickRow:function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e){var curPage =$("#gridTable").getGridParam("page");//current page var pageSize = $("#gridTable").getGridParam("rowNum");//records per pagevar count = parseInt((curPage-1)*pageSize) + parseInt(rowid);}
```